# OpenCV writing to XML incorrectly-- nodes repeating

Tags: c++, xml, opencv

I'm writing to an XML fle in OpenCV and I'm running into an issue where the nodes are being written incorrectly.  My code:

```
FileStorage fs(s.outputFileName, FileStorage::WRITE);  

fs << "camera_matrix" << cameraMatrix;          
fs << "distCoeffs" << distCoeffs;       
fs << "image_width" << imageSize.width;    
fs << "image_height" << imageSize.height;

fs.release();
```

`cameraMatrix` and `distCoeffs` are both Mat objects.

My XML output file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<camera_matrix type_id="opencv-matrix">
   <rows>3</rows>
   <cols>3</cols>
   <dt>d</dt>
   <data>
    4.6490822605835838e+003 0. 1.4075000000000000e+003 0.
    4.6490822605835838e+003 9.3950000000000000e+002 0. 0. 1  </data></camera_matrix>
<camera_matrix>distCoeffs</camera_matrix>
<camera_matrix type_id="opencv-matrix">
   <rows>5</rows>
   <cols>1</cols>
   <dt>d</dt>
   <data>
    -1.1104540491479253e-001 3.2257882031809664e+000 0. 0.
    -3.2884118325204533e+001</data></camera_matrix>
<image_width>2816</image_width>
<image_width>image_height</image_width>
<image_width>1880</image_width>
</opencv_storage>
```

For some reason instead of storing the `distCoeffs` Mat object as a node with the name `<distCoeffs>`, it stores it with the name `<camera_matrix>`, and instead of storing the integer `image_height` under the node name `<image_height>` it is stored under `<image_width>`.  Why would this be happening?  I took a look at the [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html) but couldn't find what I am doing wrong.  Using OpenCV 3.0.0 with Visual Studio 2013.

Edit:  I am able to reproduce the error with this test code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <iostream>


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

static void saveCameraParams(Mat c, Mat d);
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat cameraMatrix = Mat(3, 3, CV_64F, cvScalar(0.));
    Mat distCoeffs = Mat(5, 1, CV_64F, cvScalar(0.));
    saveCameraParams(cameraMatrix, distCoeffs);

}
static void saveCameraParams(Mat cameraMatrix, Mat distCoeffs)
    {
        Size imageSize;
        imageSize.width = 3;
        imageSize.width = 4;
        FileStorage fs("test_out.xml", FileStorage::WRITE);

        fs << "camera_matrix" << cameraMatrix;

        fs << "distCoeffs" << distCoeffs;

        fs << "image_width" << imageSize.width;

        fs << "image_height" << imageSize.height;

        fs.release();
}
```

Comment: Works for me, OpenCV 300 and VS 2013. You're probably messing things up elsewhere in your code. Does it works correctly if you use YML extension?

Comment: Nope, same issue.  Earlier in the code I am reading from an XML file, but I'm not sure how that would affect writing to XML/YML files at all.

Comment: Try to post a small sample code that will reproduce your error.

Comment: except that you're not initializing imageSize.height, the code works as expected for me.

Comment: Figured it out.  One of the other projects in my solution was the wrong platform, and changing that to the correct one fixed the problem.   Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with the platform I was using.  In my solution one of the other projects had the incorrect platform.  Fixing that fixed the problem.